# Create network from points in QGIS using grouping variables

Tags: qgis, network

There seem to be some answers for this problem for ArcMap, but not for QGIS.

I have a set of points representing the power grid and I want to produce a network from them. Here's my data:

```
ID     lat_from    lat_to   lon_from    lon_to    voltage
1        51.1       51.2      0.2        0.97      400
1        51.2       51.9      0.96       0.84      400
1        51.4       51.8      0.5        0.37      275
1        51.6       51.7      0.7        0.57      400
1        51.7       51.6      0.6        0.67      275
1        51.8       51.4      0.9        0.97      400
```

Many of the tools don't seem to accept directional connections (from point x to point y) or grouping variables (e.g. voltage)

I'm looking for something like this:

[image]

Are there any suggestions for how to do this?

Comment: What tools have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I do in that case is to concatenate the coordinates to create a line in [WKT format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text):

```
LINESTRING (51.1 0.2, 51.2 0.97)
```

This can be done in many ways, for example using CONCATENATE in Excel or LibreOffice.

Then the file can be saved as csv, keeping any needed attributes as additional columns, and opened in QGIS using "Add delimited text layer" and choosing the WKT linestring column as geometry.

Then the attributes can be used to create an adequate symbology.

Answer (score 0):

As Leyan say, I think WKT is a good opcion. 
Perhaps you can explore the mmqgis plugin:
http://michaelminn.com/linux/mmqgis/
good luck